# Find out the type of an automounted device

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fstab, automount

I'm working on a system (Ubuntu Precise) with a mount defined in `/etc/fstab` as follows:

```
/dev/vdb        /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0       2
```

Originally I just wanted to find out if it's NFS (due to potential MySQL locking issues). Judging from `man mount`, it's not:

```
If no -t option is given, or if the auto type is specified, mount will try to guess the desired type.  Mount uses the blkid library for guessing  the
filesystem type; if that does not turn up anything that looks familiar, mount will try to read the file /etc/filesystems, or, if that does not exist,
/proc/filesystems.  All of the filesystem types listed there will be tried, except for those that are labeled "nodev" (e.g., devpts, proc  and  nfs).
If /etc/filesystems ends in a line with a single * only, mount will read /proc/filesystems afterwards.
```

But, out of curiosity now, how can I find out more about what type of device it actually is? (For context, this is a VM running on OpenStack. The device is a 60Gb allocation mounted from somewhere - but I don't know how.)`

EDIT Including answers here:

```
$ mount
/dev/vdb on /mnt type ext3 (rw,_netdev)

$ df -T
/dev/vdb                       ext3        61927420     2936068   55845624   5% /mnt
```

Comment: What's `mount` say?

Comment: Whoops, that was easy. ext3. `/dev/vdb on /mnt type ext3 (rw,_netdev)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you be satisfied with just `df -T /mnt` ? :)

Comment: Yep, that's very satisfying!